# Terraforming s3 replication - stuck in remove then add cycle

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Basically I am trying to create a simple module to create s3 buckets for our product.  We have a bunch of requirements like logging and replication.  But don't have to have replication on the log bucket.  Seems simple right.  And it wasn't terrible.  But I ran it once and it created everything and looked good.  ran it again... it detected changes.

I gave the replication rule a static ID so that it wouldn't try to replace it every time.  But now it wants to remove the aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration on Run B, and then put it back on Run C (rinse, repeat)

Here is a ticket on terrform that I followed but didn't help.  https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/665

Here is the bucket creation and replication code

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name

  acl = var.is_logging_bucket ? "log-delivery-write" : "private"

  dynamic "logging" {
    for_each = var.is_logging_bucket ? [] : [1]
    content {
      target_bucket = var.logging_bucket_name
      target_prefix = "${var.bucket_name}/"
    }
  }

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = var.bucket_name
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "replication" {
  count = var.is_logging_bucket ? 0 : 1
  # Must have bucket versioning enabled first
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.this]

  role   = aws_iam_role.replication[0].arn
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id

  rule {
    id = "${var.bucket_name}"
    status = "Enabled"
    priority = 0
    delete_marker_replication {
      status = "Disabled"
    }
    filter {}
    destination {
      bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.replication_dest[0].arn
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
    }
  }
}
```

I added the rule id, delete_marker_replication, priority and filter based on the above linked git issue.

This is what the plan output has

```
  # module.storage-files.aws_s3_bucket.this will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
        id                          = "foo-storage-files"
        tags                        = {
            "Name" = "foo-storage-files"
        }
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - replication_configuration {
          - role = "arn:aws:iam::719971311053:role/s3-replication-role-foo-storage-files-backup" -> null

          - rules {
              - id       = "foo-storage-files" -> null
              - priority = 0 -> null
              - status   = "Enabled" -> null

              - destination {
                  - bucket        = "arn:aws:s3:::foo-storage-files-backup" -> null
                  - storage_class = "STANDARD" -> null
                }

              - filter {}
            }
        }

        # (3 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

And versions

```
  required_version = "~> 1.2.9"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      version = "~> 3.73.0"
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can get it to stop trying to remove the replication every other run?

Comment: Have you tried working with any provider version > 4?

Comment: I read a lot of complaints about s3 parameter issues in higher versions that caused people to have to import all there buckets and do a bunch of stuff.  And being a major version change, I imagine that would require a lot of code updates in the code base.  Any reason to believe that would fix this specifically?

Comment: Is this a module for testing or production codebase?

Comment: Both.  One codebase, several workspaces.

Comment: Well, you're probably going to have to move to a new(er) provider version, so I guess it's better sooner than later. However, that might be a bug in the provider version, so maybe you can just do a minor version bump if so.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you think the version is the cause?

Comment: No, but moving to 3.x.x will not break anything, it can only give you valuable bug fixes. Additionally, the 3.73.0 version is 9 months old so there have probably beens some important changes in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" resource is conflicting with empty "replication_configuration" block in the "aws_s3_bucket" resource configuration.
I have fixed the issue by adding

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "replication_configuration"
    ]
  }
```

block to "aws_s3_bucket"
There is a note about that here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.74.2/docs/resources/s3_bucket_replication_configuration
As an alternative you might want to move your replication configuration from the separate resource to "replication_configuration" block right inside "aws_s3_bucket" resource configuration.